# ImportError when Importing Classes

Tags: python, import, module, package, importerror

I have a question about an issue with importing modules/packages that I cant seem to wrap my head around if anyone could clear up my confusion.
I have a main folder called parent_directory
Inside this I have two packages, package1 contains the modules, module1, module2 and a folder called package2, the subfolder package2 contains the module, module3

[image: package,module structure]

module1.py contains

```
class module1:
print("I am MODULE 1 in PACKAGE 1")
```

module2.py contains

```
class module1:
print("I am MODULE 2 in PACKAGE 1")
```

module3.py contains

```
class module3:
print("I am MODULE 3 in PACKAGE 2")
```

When I open OOP lab3.py
and use the following

```
from package1.module1 import module1
module1()
```

The printout is, I am MODULE 1 in PACKAGE 1 which is what I expect, however, if I change this to

```
from package1.module2 import module2
module2()
```

The printout is, I am MODULE 2 in PACKAGE 1 which again is what I expect, but I also get the error

> File "D:/Docs/Programming/Python/parent_directory/OOP lab 3.py", line 8, in 
> from package1.module2 import module2
> ImportError: cannot import name 'module2' from 'package1.module2' (D:\Docs\Programming\Python\parent_directory\package1\module2.py)

If module 1 & 2 are in the same package I dont understand why I am getting the import error and if I'm getting the import error why am I getting the print out with what I would expect had I been able to import module2 what is adding to my confusion is that I have no issue with module3 when using

```
from package1.package2.module3 import module3
module3()
```

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Why is the name `module1` in the file file `module2` isn't that the error ?

Comment: Thanks @azro had just spotted that

Comment: @azro I made a typo in Module2.py I should have called the class module2 instead of module1, thanks for spotting it

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the issue, I made a typo in Module2.py as

```
class module1:
    print("I am MODULE 2 in PACKAGE 1")
```

it should have been

```
class module2:
    print("I am MODULE 2 in PACKAGE 1")
```

Comment: Don't answer to typos answer, they will be flagged and close, thanks